# Por que al insertar datos en mysql el campo sale vació (el texto), y solo muestra números?

Tags: php, mysql

Que tal, tengo una duda, ojala alguien me pueda orientar
Tengo un botón llamado "AGREGAR" que al seleccionar,sale una ventana modal, en la cual hay dos cajas de texto, una llamada "txt_nombre" y otra llamada "txt_costo" y un boton "GUARDAR".
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer click en el botón GUARDAR, los datos se tienen que almacenar en mi BD, en mi tabla llamada "trabajos", la cual tiene tres campos (Id_trabajo, Nombre_Trabajo y Costo), pero el problema, es que al mandar los datos, no sale texto en el campo "Nombre_Trabajo, simplemente sale el Id, y el Costo que ingrese anteriormente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que puede ser? porque no sale el tetxo que ingrese? ojala me puedan ayudar
Les dejo mi código del formulario

```html
<!--Boton para agregar un nuvo trabajo a  la lista-->
<div id="btnAddUser" class="center addUser">
  <div class='col-xs-6'>
      <h3 class='text-right'>
        <button id="goNuevoUser" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i> Agregar</button>
      </h3>
  </div>
</div>
 
 
<!--MODAL PARA AGREGAR UN NUEVO trabajo A LA BD Y A LA TABLA-->
<!-- Modal-->
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="validacion_modal.php">
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!--Cabecera del modal-->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo Trabajo</h4>
      </div>
      <!--Contenido del modal-->
      <div class="modal-body">
 
 
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xm-6">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txt_nombre" name="txt_nombre" placeholder="Nombre del trabajo" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
 
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xm-6">
          <input class="form-control " type="text" id="txt_costo" name="txt_costo" placeholder="Costo" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--Final del modal-->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="width: 100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </form>
```

y mi código de php que hace la consulta

```html
<?
$conexion= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "registros");
if($conexion)
{
 
 
  //Variables
 
  $Nombre_Trabajo = $_POST['txt_trabajo'];
  $Costo=$_POST['txt_costo'];
 
 
//realiza la consulta
  $consulta= "INSERT INTO trabajos (Nombre_Trabajo, Costo) values ( '$Nombre_Trabajo', '$Costo')";
 
 
 
//para ejecutar consulta
  $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion ,$consulta);
 
 
  if ($resultado) {   ?>
 
      <div class="alert alert-success">
      <strong>Datos guardados correctamente!</strong>
      <a href="consulta_lista.php" class="alert-link">Volver</a>
      </div>
 
      <?php  }
 
      else { ?>
 
      <div class="alert alert-warning">
      <strong>Error al guardar los datos!</strong>
      <a href="consulta_lista.php" class="alert-link">Volver</a>
      </div>
 
      <?php }
 
 
      }
      else{
        echo "";
      }
        mysqli_close($conexion);
      ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Realmente estás intentando recuperar un valor del formulario que no existe. Tendrías que recuperarlo así:

```
$Nombre_Trabajo = $_POST['txt_nombre'];
```

donde pone:

```
$Nombre_Trabajo = $_POST['txt_trabajo'];
```

Comment: gracias por darse el tiempo!

Comment: @Rms De nada. Por favor, considera aceptar la respuesta que te haya sido más útil de las tres como respuesta aceptada. Para ello, puedes usar el tick que hay a la izquierda de cada respuesta (sólo lo podrás usar para una sola respuesta y se pondrá en verde). Para agradecer, puedes dar un voto positivo (ahí si que puedes a más de una respuesta) también a la izquierda de la respuesta en la flecha hacia arriba. Un saludo! :)

Answer (score 2):

El texto no sale porque el `input` tiene `name="txt_nombre"` pero luego en el PHP lo que lees es `$_POST['txt_trabajo']`. Corrige el PHP para que lea `$_POST['txt_nombre']` y eso solucionará tu problema:

```
//Variables

$Nombre_Trabajo = $_POST['txt_nombre'];
$Costo=$_POST['txt_costo'];
```

Aparte de eso, tu código presenta problemas de seguridad graves y puede sufrir ataques de inyección SQL que deberías corregir antes de ponerlo en producción y de cara al público. Lee [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php) para más información.

Comment: gracias me funciono, y eso como lo puedo evitar?

Comment: Lo puedes ver en el enlace de arriba. La idea principal es que usar MySQLi como haces es un buen primer paso, pero no es suficiente; Debes también usar sentencias preparadas en lugar de dinámicas.

Answer (score 1):

En tu `html` tienes:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xm-6">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txt_nombre" name="txt_nombre" placeholder="Nombre del trabajo" required="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Y en tu `PHP`:

```
$Nombre_Trabajo = $_POST['txt_trabajo'];
$Costo=$_POST['txt_costo'];
```

Cambia tu `PHP` a:

```
$Nombre_Trabajo = $_POST['txt_nombre']; // <-- El mismo nombre del input en tu html, ese es tu error
$Costo=$_POST['txt_costo'];
```

Comment: muchas gracias!